# Folder browser/picker breaks when ported to Mac

Tags: macos, excel, vba

I've been searching for awhile for an answer to this, almost all were vague, so I'm still pretty clueless. I created a program that opens 2 files, synchronizes them, and then saves the file to a location the user chooser. Works perfect on Windows, which is what I assumed it would run on (stupid assumptions...), but is broken on Mac. I've been able to fix the opening of folders, but I need the saving section fixed. Heres the code:

```
Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
Dim sItem As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath

    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing

sFile = "\" & sSubID & "-" & sSubSession & "-synced.txt"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sItem & sFile, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows, CreateBackup:=False
End Function
```

I need to be able to control the NAME of the file with the program (subject's ID and session ID) but I need the FOLDER to save it to. I'm pretty knew to Mac, but pick up on things relatively quickly. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future searchers:

```
Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim folderPath As String
Dim RootFolder As String

sFile = sSubID & "-" & sSubSession & "-synced.txt"
On Error Resume Next
RootFolder = MacScript("return (path to desktop folder) as String")
folderPath = MacScript("(choose folder with prompt ""Select the folder""" & _
"default location alias """ & RootFolder & """) as string")
On Error GoTo 0

If folderPath <> "" Then
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=folderPath & sFile, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows, CreateBackup:=False
End If
```

Please note, after a few pages on Google, I finally stumbled upon this site:
http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/section3.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your problem :

```
sFile = "\" & sSubID & "-" & sSubSession & "-synced.txt"
```

Backslash `\` are specific for Windows paths. For UNIX based OS, you have to use `/`.

Some tip found on the Internet to have a cross-platform path :

```
Application.PathSeparator
```

For your line, it would be :

```
sFile = Application.PathSeparator & sSubID & "-" & sSubSession & "-synced.txt"
```

Comment: Yeah, that's just the code for windows, I had adjusted that and tried posting it from the MacBook, however, it/Safari won't load the text editing options, so I shifted to my windows computer and posted it, my apologies

Comment: That was the problem, I had no idea what to do for the Mac:/ However, I did find a solution. I still have no idea how it does what it does, but it works. I'll post below once I can get it formatted :)

Comment: So there is still a problem or not ? Don't understand

Comment: There is not, the solution I provided ended up working. Turns out it was deep in the results from a popular search engine.. Thank you for reviewing the code.

Comment: The solution is always in depths of Google ^^